# How to use ML Kit cloud text recognizer for flutter?

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, google-cloud-vision, firebase-mlkit

I am using the package 'firebase_ml_vision' in my project to do OCR. I can read Latin based languages just fine, however, I want to read Chinese characters. I know that there are on the device and cloud-based versions of the text recognizer. However, I can't find out how to 'enable' the cloud-based version in my app. I have already activated cloud-based APIs in Firebase as seen in this image:
[Activated cloud apis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MahE.png)

The code that I currently use is:

```
void _initializeVision() async{
final File imageFile = File(imagePath);
final FirebaseVisionImage visionImage = FirebaseVisionImage.fromFile(imageFile);


final TextRecognizer textRecognizer = FirebaseVision.instance.textRecognizer();
final VisionText visionText = await textRecognizer.processImage(visionImage);



for(TextBlock blocks in visionText.blocks){
  for(TextLine line in blocks.lines){
    print(line.text);
  }
}}
```

[Image I try to read](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYSFR.png)

Results:

```
I/flutter (10432): FamilyMart Collection
I/flutter (10432): 10
I/flutter (10432): Pocket facial tissue
I/flutter (10432): Without fluorescent virgin fber from wood puip
I/flutter (10432): pampers your skin
```

Can anyone explain to me how to use cloud text recognizer for Flutter?

Comment: NOTE: you should use `FirebaseVision.instance.cloudTextRecognizer().processImage(fbi)` but it still produce much less accurate results than the suggested answer

Answer (score 1):

Have the same problem, don't think cloud-OCR currently works with the ML-Package. I managed to make it work via a POST request.
Here is everything you need: [Make Vision API request](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/request?hl=en#providing_the_image)

```
// Upload Image to Firebase and get
// 1. DownloadUrl or 
// 2. StorageBucket or
//
// 3. Convert Image to base64 with
// String base64Image = base64Encode(File(imagePath).readAsBytesSync());
// (does not work for me, if you use this way make sure your `body` is correct)

String body = """{
  'requests': [
    {
      'image': {
        'source': {
          'imageUri': '$downloadUrl'
        }
      },
      'features': [
        {
          'type': 'DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION'
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}""";

http.Response res = await http
  .post(
    "https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate?key=$API_KEY",
    body: body
  );

print("${res.body}");
```